# Complex processing of two list of lists in Python (with Joins on multiple items)

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy

I have requirement to merge two list of lists while joining/merging them on few items in each list of lists. I am very new to the python programming, please bear with me here. 
I have two list of lists : AppNodes list of lists and Applications list of lists. Please see below.
I have tried to do with nested forloops but it just got so dirty and giving me wrong output. 
Is there a better and efficient way to do it. 
Please help me on this. I want to learn a lot in Python.

```
List_Of_Lists_A : (Applications list)

AppliactationName                           Version  AppSpace           App_Status   
XpathExtensions.application                 1.0      DOBAdapter-A       Stopped  
AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapter            1.1      DOBAdapter-A       Stopped  
AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension2  1.1      DOBAdapter-A       Stopped  
AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension   1.1      DOBAdapter-A       Stopped  





List_Of_Lists_B : (Appnodes list)


AppNodeName                                  AppNode_Status     AppSpace                 MgmtPort  Agent                      ConfigState          Up Time
DOBAdapter-A-Node4                           Running            DOBAdapter-A             8888      machine1                   InSync               56d 00:23:07
DOBAdapter-A-Node1                           Running            DOBAdapter-A             8888      Machine2                   InSync               56d 01:47:10
DOBAdapter-A-Node3                           Running            DOBAdapter-A             8888      machine3                   InSync               54d 22:39:09
DOBAdapter-A-Node2                           Running            DOBAdapter-A             8888      machine4                   InSync               55d 01:58:12
DOBAdapter-A-Node5                           Running            DOBAdapter-A             8888      Machine5                   InSync               55d 22:38:30




Required Output : (may be in nice tabular format if possible)

Domain  AppSpace        AppNodeName         Port    AppNode_Status  Application                                 App_Status      Version     Agent
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node4  8888    Running         XpathExtensions.application                 Stopped          1.0        machine1
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node4  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapter            Stopped          1.1        machine1
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node4  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension2  Stopped          1.1        machine1
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node4  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension   Stopped          1.1        machine1
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node1  8888    Running         XpathExtensions.application                 Stopped          1.0        machine2
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node1  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapter            Stopped          1.1        machine2
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node1  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension2  Stopped          1.1        machine2
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node1  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension   Stopped          1.1        machine2
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node3  8888    Running         XpathExtensions.application                 Stopped          1.0        machine3
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node3  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapter            Stopped          1.1        machine3
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node3  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension2  Stopped          1.1        machine3
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node3  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension   Stopped          1.1        machine3
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node2  8888    Running         XpathExtensions.application                 Stopped          1.0        machine4
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node2  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapter            Stopped          1.1        machine4
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node2  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension2  Stopped          1.1        machine4
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node2  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension   Stopped          1.1        machine4
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node5  8888    Running         XpathExtensions.application                 Stopped          1.0        machine5
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node5  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapter            Stopped          1.1        machine5
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node5  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension2  Stopped          1.1        machine5
UAT     TestAppSpace    DOBAdapter-A-Node5  8888    Running         AWS.bw.enterprise.API.DOBAdapterExtension   Stopped          1.1        machine5
```

Comment: Each Application is deployed on each of the machine as an Instance. so that is why each appnode has all 4 of those applications running on all 5 machines.

Comment: Domain name and AppSpace names as passed as arguments.

Comment: Domain : sys.argv[1]  
AppSpace : sys.argv[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this with nested for loops isn't terrible

```
output = []
for row in appnodes_list:
    table1_item = row[2]
    for row2 in apps_list:
        table2_item = row2[2]
        if table1_item == table2_item:
            new_row = row + row2
            output.append(new_row)
```

The only thing you would need to update here is which element to join on. This is assuming you are joining on the AppSpace column, which is the second index of each table (hence row[2] and row2[2]) in the code above.

Comment if you have any questions.